# Python - pickle.dump() without a file

Tags: python

This is the code I have:

```
with open(testify, 'w') as fh:
    pickle.dump((f,t), fh)
```

I need the data in my code without dumping it to a file because it needs to be send to remote location.

I have tried:

```
data = pickle.dumps(f, t)
```

but it did not work.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pickle.dumps((f, t))` to dump to a string instead

Comment: How can it be done? I have tried: data = pickle.dumps(f, t) but it did not work.

Comment: Are you trying to dump the tuple `(f,t)`? Try `pickle.dumps((f,t))`.

Comment: what are f and t?

Comment: @TrevorHickey - they are just the variables from the question. The problem is that `pickle.dumps` accepts one argument, but the op wanted to pass it a tuple with two items in it but was missing the extra brackets.